# Insert select2 tags jQuery array in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, jquery-select2

I have seen many threads on stackoverflow about this concern but I couldn't achieve that so that made this post again. I am using `select2 jQuery plugin` where I want to insert Tags in SQL using PHP. Like [`Data, Data, Data`]

I try to do that which I learn through google, well I am professionalize in this, I am new in PHP.
Please help 'How I Insert this in DB where show `,` between two words as above I mentioned in `Like`'

*My Code Is*

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = "Your_Name";
    $email = "Your_Email";

    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `email`, `color_name`) VALUES (':name',':email',':color')");
    foreach ($data as $row)
    {
        ':name' = $name;
        ':email' = $email;
        ':color' = 'MYStatus'; //I want mention here Select2 Tags Data and insert in DB where [, (space)] every two words. like [Green, Red, Blue, Pink] 
        $stmt->execute();
    }
  }
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://shashani-humanth.github.io/Notebook-AdminPanel/js/select2/select2.css">
</head>
<body>
<form class="bs-example form-horizontal" id="formid" method="POST" onSubmit="return validate();">

    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="selectname[]" id="select2-tags" style="width:260px" value="brown"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="submit">Save and Publish</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script src="http://shashani-humanth.github.io/Notebook-AdminPanel/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://shashani-humanth.github.io/Notebook-AdminPanel/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://shashani-humanth.github.io/Notebook-AdminPanel/js/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    if ($.fn.select2) {
      $("#select2-option").select2();
      $("#select2-tags").select2({
        tags:["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Pink"],
        tokenSeparators: [",", " "]}
      );
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is likely being sent like this:

```
Array
(
    [selectname] => Array
        (
            [0] => brown,Green,Blue
        )

)
```

So, since you are wanting it to be formatted as `brown, Green, Blue`, then you can `explode()` and `implode()` or just use a `str_replace()`:

```
# Exploding, imploding
$tags = implode(", ", explode(",", $_POST['selectname'][0]));

# String replace would be
$tags = str_replace(',', ', ', $_POST['selectname'][0]);
```

If you are trying to split up that string to insert each tag separately, you would use `explode()` on the comma, then loop the results of the `explode()`.

I would probably use `trim()` in there to remove empty space, just incase. Also, if you want to make sure they are all formatted the same, you might want to do `ucwords()` to make sure each word has an uppercase as the first letter *(your default value `brown` is all lower and the reset have the first letters upper)*.

If you do method 1, you can apply a `ucfirst()` and `trim()` if you use `array_map()` on the exploded string:

```
# A full combination of functions
$tags = implode(", ", array_map(function($v){
    return ucfirst(trim($v));
}, explode(",", $_POST['selectname'][0])));
```

would give you the string:

```
Brown, Green, Blue
```

---

**EDIT:**

Since you are actually storing per row, you can fetch back to an array using a `select`:

```
function getColorTags($name, $con)
{
    # Query by name, just return the color_name field though
    $query = $con->prepare("SELECT `color_name` FROM `test` WHERE `name` = ?");
    # Execute the query with bind value
    $query->execute([$name]);
    # Loop the results
    while($result = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        # Store the tags
        $row[] = $result['color_name'];
    }
    # Return the tags or an empty array
    return (isset($row))? $row : [];
}
```

To use:

```
# Fetch the tags by name, make sure to inject the database connection
$tags = getColorTags('Some Name', $con);
# Print out the array
print_r($tags);
```

---

**EDIT #2**

To do it both together on the same page, you would just use `json_encode()`:

```
<?php
function insertTags($data, $email, $name, $con)
{
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `email`, `color_name`) VALUES (?,?,?)");

    foreach ($data as $string) {
        # Explode and filter the tags from the js
        $arr = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(',', $string)));
        # Loop the "selectname"
        foreach($arr as $tag) {
            # Execute all the rows
            $stmt->execute([$name, $email, $tag]);
        }
    }
}
# This fetches using the email as the primary key
function getColorTags($email, $con)
{
    # Query by name, just return the color_name field though
    $query = $con->prepare("SELECT `color_name` FROM `test` WHERE `email` = ?");
    # Execute the query with bind value
    $query->execute([$name]);
    # Loop the results
    while($result = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        # Store the tags
        $row[] = $result['color_name'];
    }
    # Return the tags or an empty array
    return (isset($row))? $row : [];
}

# Pull these out so you can use them in general
$name = "Your_Name"; // Assuming this is from the session
$email = "Your_Email"; // Assuming this is from the session
# Here is where you insert
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    # This will insert your tags separately on new rows
    insertTags($_POST['selectname'], $email, $name, $con);
    # This will pull them back from the database (helpful if they already have some in there)
    $tags = getColorTags($email, $con);
}
# Here you check if there are tags already generated after submission,
# if not, then pull them.
if(!isset($tags))
    $tags = getColorTags($email, $con);
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://shashani-humanth.github.io/Notebook-AdminPanel/js/select2/select2.css">
</head>
<body>
<form class="bs-example form-horizontal" id="formid" method="POST" onSubmit="return validate();">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="selectname[]" id="select2-tags" style="width:260px" value="brown"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="submit">Save and Publish</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="http://shashani-humanth.github.io/Notebook-AdminPanel/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://shashani-humanth.github.io/Notebook-AdminPanel/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://shashani-humanth.github.io/Notebook-AdminPanel/js/select2/select2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    if ($.fn.select2) {
        $("#select2-option").select2();
        $("#select2-tags").select2({
            // Now use this native function to echo the array back to JS
            tags: <?php echo json_encode($tags) ?>,
            tokenSeparators: [",", " "]}
        );
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much could your help me once again in this same thread, Is not possible to make `<option>Green</option>` like tags in this `select2` box. I am currently fetching the options from js code. `or` How I write a code in php which show  `tags:["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Pink"],` like this fetch from db where table name is `dummy`

Comment: Oh you want to fetch the tags as an array after saving it as such? If that is the case, it depends on how you are saving the tags. If you are saving all tags in one row or in multiple, then it’s different.

Comment: I am saving the tag in every each column

Comment: I have demonstrated the fetch based on the per-row example.

Comment: `error : syntax error, unexpected ')' ` and how I echo  in script module could you PHPFiddle me ?

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault, it was supposed to be `while` not `foreach`

Comment: Thanks, but I not understand here `('Some Name', $con);` `some name ?` Could you tell me how I add in script as in my thread.. pls

Comment: I am assuming that you have a primary key you are drawing from your database, so it looks like it would be `name` or `email`? I just picked `name`, but it's probably `email`, assuming that is unique to each user in your db so whatever one you are using, you have to change the `SELECT` statement to use `email` and then replace `Some Name` with the email address of the person you are fetching the tags for.

Comment: `https://i.ibb.co/DMtRMV0/js.png` and `https://i.ibb.co/xhY9q4r/php.png` But this is not working for me how I show in js script like in image ?

Comment: Oh, I see what you are trying to (kind of ) do. The `$tags` should not be imploded if you are trying to display them back into that javascript (presumably the javascript is in the html of the page on the same page as the php). I will edit for that change.

Comment: It was wonderful experience and I learnt a-lot through your code, In my mindset I always learn via code instead theory or documentation. I don't know why its happens. well `bit.ly/2HWI45O` could you help me in this last.